# Mootools JSON.encode missing while MooTools is loaded

Tags: javascript, json, request, mootools

I am experiencing a very strange problem with MooTools 1.3 on our end users side (I cannot reproduce it):

JSON.encode and JSON.decode are undefined while MooTools is loaded (I checked it using `if (!window.MooTools) {...}`), JSON is defined.

This causes the Request.JSON (also a MooTools method) to fail on valid successful response (Request.JSON uses JSON.decode to parse the response).

Did anyone experienced such problems with MooTools? Any ideas on how to attack this problem?

Comment: to be fair, `window.JSON` should be defined by the (modernish) browser anyway because of `JSON.parse`/`stringify`, as for MooTools - it has always been in the build. 1.3.2 tagged code: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/1.3.2/Source/Utilities/JSON.js - it falls back to native if available. you may be running a custom build of mootools.

Comment: We use mootools-core-1.3-full-nocompat.js, which does not have this fallback. I've managed to hack patch this issue but what I'm really trying to do is understand why does these methods disappear on some rare cases and find the root cause of it.

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log (JSON);`? What methods are in that object?

Comment: I cannot console.log as I cannot reproduce it (and I don't want to send the full JSON object to the BI servers). I made a fallback to check and use JSON.stringify if JSON.encode is missing so I know for sure JSON is defined and so does stringify.

Comment: sounds like you have a different race condition. requirejs? if so change shim to wait for JSON.encode not window.MooTools

Comment: Cannot think of a way that MooTools can be defined and JSON.encode is not

Comment: When you write: _"JSON.encode and JSON.decode are undefined while MooTools is loaded (I checked it using if (!window.MooTools) {...})"_ -> how did you do that test? `!window.MooTools` will be true __before__ MooTools is loaded. How are you loading MooTools? Require.JS, in `<head>`, other?

Comment: @Sergio either way, it is fine - but he may have `async=true` on the tag or have it as a peer dep in his dep manager rather than a required dep. also, this implies he has loaded mootools, does request.JSON and gets to a result already, at which point it fails. this will not be a loader thing probably. suggest adding `Object.observe` on `JSON` and seeing what removes the methods. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

Comment: Thanks Dimitar, is there any way to know who made the change (what function, code, file, etc) using Object.observe?

Comment: @Technotronic sure. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/ffrp27qk/ in chrome - look for removal as we know mootools-core has it. somebody is removing when they shouldn't. problem is with this, you cannot get a stack trace but if you prove it, you can search your codebase for `delete JSON.encode`;

Comment: another thing you can do is you can use `Object.defineProperty(JSON, 'encode', { writeble: false });` or `Object.freeze` to prevent interference. or do `(function(f){
f = {writable:!1};Object.defineProperties(JSON, {encode:f,decode:f});
}());` after mootools loads to prevent changes if  `Object.freeze` is unavailable